# Get the status of an object on eventhandling in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My source code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>onload test</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="spot.css" media="screen" />
     
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome Page</h1>
  
  <script>
  
      debugger;
      function constructScripts(url, callBack) {
          var script = document.createElement("script");
          script.type = "text/javascript";
          script.src = url;
          document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
          if (script.readyState) {
              script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                  if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
                      script.onreadystatechange = null; callBack();
                  }
              };
          }
          else {
              script.onload = callBack;
          }
      }
      
      
  </script>
  <script>
      debugger;
      myCallBack = function () {
          alert(this.src + "loaded");
      }

      constructScripts("files1", myCallBack);
      constructScripts("files2", myCallBack);
      constructScripts("files3", myCallBack);

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

`this.src` is undefined here. I guess this should be an 'script' object which supposed to have its src property so that I can read the filename. Who is `this` here? And also when I view the page source these scripts were not included in the header() section. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

> this.src is undefined here.

It shouldn't be… It is defined earlier: `script.src = url`

> I guess this should be an 'script' object which supposed to have its src property so that i can read the filename. Who is 'this' here?

The script element upon which the `onload` or `readystatechange` event fires

> And also when i view the page source these scripts were not included in the header() section. Why is it so?

Because you are looking at the page source, not a serialisation of the live DOM after it has been manipulated by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

When you call you `callBack` function, pass it the script object like `callBack(script)`. Modify the `callBack` function like

```
myCallBack = function (script) {
      alert(script.src + "loaded");
  }
```

View source does not show dinamically loaded elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your function using prototype.

```
Element.prototype.MyMethod = function(){}
```

Look at your edited code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>onload test</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="spot.css" media="screen" />

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome Page</h1>

  <script>
        Element.prototype.MyMethod = function(){}
      function constructScripts(url, callBack) {
          var script = document.createElement("script");
          script.type = "text/javascript";
          script.src = url;
          script.MyMethod = callBack;
          document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
          if (script.readyState) {
              script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                  if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
                      script.onreadystatechange = null; 
              script.MyMethod();
                  }
              };
          }
          else {
              script.onload = callBack;
          }
      }


  </script>
  <script>
      myCallBack = function () {
          alert(this.src + "loaded");
      }

      constructScripts("files1", myCallBack);
      constructScripts("files2", myCallBack);
      constructScripts("files3", myCallBack);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: script.MyMethod(); calls empty method and does nothing. And What is the meaning of  Element.prototype.MyMethod

Comment: Ow ya? it's fine in my browser.
It's called as prototyping to extend the methods. `document.createElement("script");
` that return Element instance as `script` calls Element object that we have extended by MyMethod. Inside the function we assign script.MyMethod to CallBack. So, when we call `script.MyMethod();`  this inside the method populated with `script`